# Get URL from HREF for .load

Tags: jquery, ajax

Looking for a way to get a product price from another page when listing products inside another page (blogs etc.)

I got it to work with Jquery below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({ url: "product-url1",
     context: document.body,
     success: function(){
      $("#priceDisplay1").load("product-url1 .price");
    }});
});
```

however if I'm displaying more than 1 product I want to try save some time rewriting code for each product

i.e.

```
<a href="product-url1"><p>Product Title 1</p></a>
<div id="priceDisplay1"></div>

<a href="product-url2"><p>Product Title 2</p></a>
<div id="priceDisplay2"></div>

<a href="product-url3"><p>Product Title 3</p></a>
<div id="priceDisplay3"></div>
```

What I want to achieve is so it can go through and get the href for each one and run the function

Answer (score 2):

First you should identify all pairs of `<a>` and `<div>`:

```
<a href="product-url1" class="iAmAPriceAnchor" data-my-display="priceDisplay1">
    <p>Product Title 1</p>
</a>
<div id="priceDisplay1"></div>

<a href="product-url2" class="iAmAPriceAnchor" data-my-display="priceDisplay2">
    <p>Product Title 2</p>
</a>
<div id="priceDisplay2"></div>

<a href="product-url3" class="iAmAPriceAnchor" data-my-display="priceDisplay3">
    <p>Product Title 3</p>
</a>
<div id="priceDisplay3"></div>
```

Once all your pairs are identified you can iterate over them and do your thing:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.iAmAPriceAnchor').each(function(){
        var priceUrl = $(this).attr('href');
        var myDisplayId = '#' + $(this).data('my-display');
        $.ajax({ 
            url: priceUrl,
            context: document.body,
            success: function(){
                $(myDisplayId).load(priceUrl + " .price");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks Joseph, got it work with a slight modification

Answer (score 0):

Got this to work by removing the `var myUrlId = $(this).id();` as this just throws an error and changing the myUrlId in the success function to priceUrl

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('.iAmAPriceAnchor').each(function(){
    var priceUrl = $(this).attr('href');
    var myDisplayId = '#' + $(this).data('my-display');
    $.ajax({ 
        url: priceUrl,
        context: document.body,
        success: function(){
            $(myDisplayId).load(priceUrl + " .price");
        }
    });
  });
 });
```